# C# Possible to have a generic return type?

Tags: c#

Here is a typical function that returns either true/false;

```cs
private static bool hasValue()
{
    return true; 
}
```

Now on an error, I would like to return my own custom error object with definition:

```cs
public class Failure
{
    public string FailureDateTime { get; set; }
    public string FailureReason { get; set; }
}
```

I would have expected to be able to throw this custom object for example...

```cs
private static bool hasValue() 
{
    try 
    {
        // do something
    }
    catch 
    {
        throw new Failure();
    }
    
    return true;
}
```

This is not possible, and I don't want to derive Failure from System.IO.Exception because I have personally had issues serializing exceptions in C# (This was with .net v2).

What is the best practice / or ideal solution to this problem. Should I just work with private static object? Or is there a cleaner way to return a custom object or bypass the typical return type on an error (not using `System.IO.Exception`)?

I am not entirely wild about using an object either, because then I need to validate the result by using casting and more boolean.

Comment: I think the only thing that can be thrown is something that derives from Exception.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This kind of solution may fit to this case:

```
var exception = new Exception();
exception.Data.Add("Failure", new Failure());
throw exception;
```

You can throw the exception (recommended to define your own exception type), and use the Data dictionary to hold the Failure. In the `catch` code you can take the data and serialize it. If you do create your own exception type you can place the Failure on a property.

*Comment: I didn't check it, but are you sure exceptions are not serializable?*

Comment: I think I will implement this solution, looks very promising.

Comment: I've had some issues serializing exceptions in practice.

Comment: I don't think it will serialize/deserialze correctly. At least, unless Failure itself is serializable.

Answer (score 7):

> I don't want to derive Failure from System.IO.Exception because of the inability to serialize an exception in C#.

The assumption that this question is based on is that you cannot serialize exceptions derived from `IOException`. However I wish to challenge this assumption. `IOException` is marked as `Serializable`. All you have to do is mark your subclass as serializable too.

See the documentation for [IOException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ioexception.aspx):

```
[SerializableAttribute]
[ComVisibleAttribute(true)]
public class IOException : SystemException
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to derive from `System.Exception` (or any other non-`sealed` subclass of it) if you want to create your own exception class. Failure to serialize that you are talking about is likely the fact that you didn't implement the serialization constructor.

Visual Studio has a code snippet that creates a recommended template for subclassing exception. You can get it by typing `exception` and pressing <kbd>tab</kbd> twice.

This is what comes out:

```
[Serializable]
public class MyException : Exception {
    public MyException() { }
    public MyException(string message) : base(message) { }
    public MyException(string message, Exception inner) : base(message, inner) { }
    protected MyException(
      System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo info,
      System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext context)
        : base(info, context) { }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inerit from Exception and make your object serializable

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry too much about this kind of situation; just create a result type to encapsulate all this logic.

```
public class ValueResult
{
  public Failure FailureDetails {get;set;}
  public bool Success {get;set;}
  public bool HasValue {get;set;}
  public object Value {get;set;}
}
```

and

```
var result = HasValue();
if(result.Success)
  DoSomething(result.Value);
else if(!result.Success)
  LogFailure(result.FailureDetails);
```

Comment: ...and you get all the elegance and robustness of programming with C style error codes... how do you let the caller's callers know about and deal with the error?

Comment: At least make it generic, instead of using a plain object.

Comment: @harms Value is whatever he wants it to be; the solution isn't meant to be a generic class to be used in any situation (no need to replace exception handling), just another option for his quesiton.  So if Value should be a MintyGreenChocolate he can simply switch that out for object.

Comment: @Pontus jump to conclusions much?  I don't recall reading in his question that he wanted to get rid of all exceptions in his application. Nor did I suggest anybody should do that.  But if you want 1) a method that does not throw exceptions, but can fail 2) may return no result, but never null and 3) doesn't hold failure information in a stateful manner then this is a good option.

Comment: Think of a TryParse method that gives you some idea of why it failed to parse, if you're having a hard time understanding why anybody would do this.

Comment: Very well, in that case I see no problem (until you need two such classes).

Comment: @Will: yep, I jumped to the assumption it's an error he's dealing with. You jumped to the assumption he wanted to get rid of exceptions,  where I read him as being unwilling to **serialize** exceptions directly. Not to be personal, but it was **your** technique I smelt something funny about. I trust you understand why I'm less than enthusiastic about non-exception error handling? Nothing in JL's questions suggests the immediate caller is the natural error handler; rather, serialization concerns rather suggest remoting... which I may of course be wrong about.

Comment: @Pontus guess we are assuming too much, heh.  The whole serializing thing doesn't make sense since exceptions are designed to serialize; they're marked with Serializable and have a special constructor for certain serialization scenarios..

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a class that inherits from Exception like this :

```
[Serializable]
public class Failure: Exception
{
    public string ErrorMessage
    {
      get
       {
         return base.Message.ToString();
       }
    }

}
```

and then

```
catch(Exception ex)
{
    throw new Failure(
          "exception message here", ex.messege);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can always use Enterprise Library Exception Handling for custom exceptions providing your own class for exception handling, formatting type, logging etc...

```
try
{
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    bool rethrow = ExceptionPolicy.HandleException(ex, "My Custom Policy");
    if (rethrow)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
finally
{
}
```

Examples:

http://weblogs.asp.net/sukumarraju/archive/2009/10/04/microsoft-enterprise-library-4-1-exception-handling-block.aspx

http://www.imason.com/imason_Blogs/b/suleman_ibrahim/archive/2009/05/25/configuring-enterprise-library-4-0-for-exception-handling-and-logging.aspx